# POSTing `JSON` to an `ArrayList` gets the response "Request JSON Mapping Error"

Tags: json, arraylist, resteasy

I have a problem POSTing `JSON` to an `ArrayList`

I have a class Plan

```
 public class Plan {
    private String planId;
    private String planName;
        :
        :
}
```

and an `ArrayList` of Plan - PlanList

```
public class PlanList {
    private List<Plan> plans = new ArrayList<Plan>();
        :
        :
}
```

I have POST and GET REST APIs

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Plan createPlan(@CookieParam(SmsHttpHeaders.X_SMS_AUTH_TOKEN) String token, Plan plan, @HeaderParam("Organization-Id") String organizationIdByService);

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PlanList createPlans(@CookieParam(SmsHttpHeaders.X_SMS_AUTH_TOKEN) String token, PlanList plans, @HeaderParam("Organization-Id") String organizationIdByService);

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PlanList retrieveAllPlans(@CookieParam(SmsHttpHeaders.X_SMS_AUTH_TOKEN) String token, @HeaderParam("Organization-Id") String organizationIdByService);
```

When I GET retrieveAllPlans, I get back the following JSON, just as I expect.

```
{
  "plans": [
    {
      "planId":"1",
      "planName":"Plan 1"
    },
    {
      "planId":"2",
      "planName":"Plan 2"
    },
    {
      "planId":"3",
      "planName":"Plan 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

POSTing a single Plan, createPlan, works correctly.
However, when I try to POST to createPlans in the same format that the GET returns, I get the response `"Request JSON Mapping Error"`.

Is the JSON incorrectly formatted? Is my REST definition wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your post functions are being mapped to the same http endpoint. There is probably a @Path notation on the class specifying a single endpoint for all its methods and RestEasy is trying to distinguish by http method (post, get, etc..).

You'll  need to specify a unique @Path annotation for each post function. Say:

```
@Path("/plan")
```

For the first, and

```
@Path("/plans")
```

For the second.

Comment: That solved the initial problem and now the POST to /plans reaches my implementation - createPlans().

Comment: I'm glad. Upvote my answer if you are inclined so I can get some more points :).

Comment: That solved the initial problem and now the POST to /plans reaches the breakpoint at the start of createPlans(). However, `plans` is always an empty PlanList.

Comment: post another question and folks will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that when you try to POST to `createPlans`, the request is being handled by `createPlan` method, because both methods are handling the same URL.

The soultion is to make two different `@Path` for these methods.